# Get more values from XPATH in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I have this HTML template:

```
<div class="item">
<span class="light">Date</span>
<a class="link" href="">2018</a>
(4pop)
</div>

<div class="item">
<span class="light">From</span>
<span>
<a class="link" href="" title="Bob" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Bob</span></a>,
</span>
<span>
<a class="link" href="" title="Peter" itemprop="url"><span itemprop="name">Peter</span></a>
</span>
</div>

<div class="item">
<span class="light">For</span>
<a class="link" href="">Bak</a>,
<a class="link" href="">Cam</a>,
<a class="link" href="">Oli</a>
</div>

<div class="item">
<span class="light">Nat</span>
<a class="link" href="">Cool</a>
</div>
</div>
```

And my Javascript code:

```
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(HTMLContent,'text/html');
var infos = doc.evaluate('//div[@class="item"]/span[1]', doc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

var nodes = [];
for(var node = infos.iterateNext(); node; node = infos.iterateNext()) {
nodes.push(node);
console.log(node.textContent);

// Until here, all things works well ! Except the code from here:
var nodde = node.nextElementSibling.attributes;

nodde.forEach(function(item){
console.log(item);
});
}
```

My goal is to get the respective value for each categorie, for example:

```
Date = 2018, (4pop)
From = Bob, Peter
For = Bak, Cam, Oli
Nat = Cool
```

I tried to iterate: `node.nextElementSibling.attributes` but without any success !

Is there a way to get the expected result please ?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML Document Object Model, DOM, is preferred as it's easier. XPATH is geared toward more rigid XML documents.

Using JavaScript, you would get data with something like:

```
var users = document.querySelectorAll('[itemprop=name]').textContent;
console.log(users);
```